# A math analysis exercise question.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

my teacher gave me this exercise:

let $f:I\to\Bbb R$ a non decreasing function, where I is an open set in $\Bbb R$, and let $S=\{x\in \Bbb R : f $ is not continuous in $x\}$; knowing that every $x \in S$ causes a "finite jump", prove that S is countable.

I wrote on the paper as it follows:

If f is not decreasing in I $\Rightarrow$ $f\in C^1(I\setminus S)$ $\Rightarrow$ the graph of the function $\Gamma_f$ is imagine of a Monge Parameterization $\Rightarrow$ is a $C^1$differentiable manifold $\Rightarrow$ is a topological manifold $\Rightarrow$ by definition of topological manifold, his connected components have a countable base $\Rightarrow$ by the continuity of f in I\S, the connected components of I\S have a countable base $\Rightarrow$ by definition of "finite jump" every couple of connected components in I\S locate a single point of S (except for inf I, sup I), then $S\setminus\{\inf I, \sup I\}$ is a countable set.

Where is the error in this approach?

Comment: You begin with "If f is not decreasing in I $\Rightarrow$ $f\in C^1(I\setminus S)$" Uhh...could it be that the left side of the first implication is not a statement? That is, "If f is not decreasing in I" cannot be $P$ in a $P \Rightarrow Q$ statement.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like more work than is necessary : Just check that every $x \in S$ causes a finite jump, which means that for each $x \in S$, there is a rational number $r_x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$
\lim_{z \to x^{-}}f(z) < r_x < \lim_{z\to x^{+}} f(z)
$$
Since $f$ is non-decreasing, for any $x\neq y$, $r_x \neq r_y$. Hence, there is an injective function from $S$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ given by
$$
x \mapsto r_x
$$
Hence, $S$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

For every jump discontinuity, $f$ changes its value by the difference of the right- and left- handed limits of the function. If there are uncountably-many of these jumps, the function will have to go to $\infty$ , i.e., consider $y=f(x)$. Then, after the jumps, f will be bounded by $\Sigma J_i$ , where $J_i$ is the $i-th$ jump. Now, there will be either uncountably-many positive jumps (meaning $f(x_i)^+-f(x_i)^- >0$ or infinitely-many negative ones. Say there infinitely-many positive jumps, WLOGenerality. Then the function will be bounded below by $y=f(x)+ \Sigma (f(x_i)^+ -f(x_i)^-)$ , where $i$ is a countable index. This sum will necessarily diverge to $\infty$, since it is an uncountable sum of positive terms.